# Use review first posts to welcome new users, don't use "No Action Needed"

Tags: discussion, new-users, review-queue

I'm seeing lots of first posts on our site that have gone through the "first review" queue but come out the other side with no action.

#### It is unacceptable that we are not using the opportunity to welcome new users

Every user's first post deserves:

- An edit if it is needed
- Comments asking for clarification if warranted
- An upvote if possible
- Their question closed if it doesn't belong here

What I'm seeing is that some folks who review lots of first posts are instead using "No Action Needed" most of the time.   The only time that a reviewer should take no action is if somebody else has already welcomed the user, the post has been edited appropriately and the post has an up vote.

Here is an anonymous example from the review queue moderator tool of a user that is not  doing the right thing:

[image]

Looking through the review history, we have several power users whose review history is similar.

Most of those "No Action Needed" questions still have zero score and no answers.   Many of them end it "thanks!" and have spelling errors.

The first post review is a great opportunity to improve this site and grow our active user base.  We are currently not taking advantage of it.   I would like to get the attention of all our users who typically review first posts.   Collectively, we need to improve the culture of this site with these reviews.

Comment: For myself, I sometimes click No Action so that I can see all the activity on the question, which the review doesn't display, since answers and comments can impact my decision. Perhaps others do the same. I _always_ read every post well (sometimes several times) and take action on the post afterwards if warranted. It certainly would be good if more were reviewing posts on a regular basis. The history for the last couple of days/weeks/months of reviews can be viewed [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history). Kudos to all of those who have been doing regular reviews!

Comment: Perfect question! You bring up the excellent point about up-votes which we just discussed. This is another perfect opportunity that just had not occurred to me. Edits are important too! I will do better. As @dan mentions I sometimes have already gone through the question before the review since reviews take a while to appear. Sometimes I attend to the question afterwards. This is because I need to take a better look. Sometimes I skip them because my attention is divided and then get back to them again later. I will take this to heart and do more. Cheers!! And Thanks!

Comment: As Dan points out, there are ways to handle reviews after clicking on the buttons, so just having "No Action Needed" on lots of reviews is not necessarily an indication of a problem.

Comment: I wrote this question in a fit of frustration and it does not have a positive tone.   I apologize for that.   I was being a bit hot headed and do not mean to criticize anybody that has been doing great work on this site.

Comment: I have not being doing my part in reviewing first posts in the last year.   I will do more reviews going forward.   It was hypocritical of me to criticize when I'm not doing any of the work myself.

Comment: I did not take your question as anything critical. Just concern and pointing out areas where we can improve just like our friend that pointed out that we are not up-voting enough. Both perfectly valid and right!! Perhaps during the recent quiet period we forgot that the smaller things are important too! It is easy enough to miss the details sometimes. I am just happy that people care. It is confirmation about what I have always said about the people here. Bloody fan-freakin-tastic!!!